# Append to nearest select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to append a function in my DataTable to the closest select filter. How can I achieve this? My function is working fine but all selects are being applied to the same table (the first one).

My function code looks like this:

```
$('#table1, table2, table3').dataTable({
    initComplete: function() {
        var column = this.api().column(0); 

        var select = $('<select class="filter"><option value=""></option></select>')
          .appendTo('#selectTriggerFilter')
          .on('change', function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            column.search(val).draw()
          });
    }
} );
```

HTML:

```
<p id="selectTriggerFilter"><label><b>FILTER:</b></label><br></p>

<table class="table table-hover dataTable" id="table1">
...
</table>


<p id="selectTriggerFilter"><label><b>FILTER:</b></label><br></p>

<table class="table table-hover dataTable" id="table2">
...
</table>
```

I did try with a variable like this to replace #selectTriggerFilter:

```
var $filter = $(this).closest("#selectTriggerFilter");
```

but its not working as intendeed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have many tables in the same view I would like to filter.  I've just updated my code to make it more clear

Comment: Thanks for editing. I've added an answer for you below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have multiple tables and with each of them there is the `<p id="selectTriggerFilter">`. The issue is when you do `.appendTo('#selectTriggerFilter')`, the selector would find the first `#selectTriggerFilter` in the whole HTML document and append it to that, which would be the first table's filter div.

The way I would approach this is the following

HTML:

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <p class="select-filter-trigger"><label><b>FILTER:</b></label></p>
    <table class="table table-hover dataTable">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
initComplete: function() {
    var column = this.api().column(0);
    var target = $(this).closest('.table-wrapper')
        .find('.select-filter-trigger');

    var select = $('<select class="filter"><option value=""></option></select>')
        .appendTo(target)
        .on('change', function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            column.search(val).draw()
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that your HTML is invalid as you're repeating the same `id` multiple times when they must be unique. Change `selectTriggerFilter` to a class.

With regard to the issue, `this` in the `initComplete` handler function will refer to the `table` element which `dataTable()` was called on. As such you need to use `prev()` to get the sibling `.selectTriggerFilter` element, not `closest() as that looks for child nodes instead. Try this:

```html
<p class="selectTriggerFilter">
  <b>FILTER:</b><br>
</p>
<table class="table table-hover dataTable"></table>

<p class="selectTriggerFilter">
  <b>FILTER:</b><br>
</p>
<table class="table table-hover dataTable"></table>
```

```js
$('#table1, table2, table3').dataTable({
  initComplete: function() {
    var column = this.api().column(0);

    var $targetFilter = $(this).prev('.selectTriggerFilter');
    var select = $('<select class="filter"><option value=""></option></select>')
      .appendTo($targetFilter)
      .on('change', function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        column.search(val).draw()
      });
  }
});
```